# Domain of the closed extension operator is not the entire space?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Given a Banach space $X$, and a densely define linear operator $A:D(A)\subset X \rightarrow X$, we define the graph 
$$G_A= \{ (x,Ax) | x\in D(A)\}$$
which is a linear subspace of Banach space $X\times X$ with norm $\|(x,y)\|_{X\times X} = \|x\|_X + \|y\|_X$.

If we take the closure of $G_A$ in $X\times X$ and $\overline{G_A}$ turns out to be the graph of another operator, we call this $\overline{A}$ the closed extension of $A$.

A general topology result we have for two sets, $\overline{(A\times B)} = \overline{A} \times\overline{B}$ in some product topological space.

My questions, given $D(A)$ is dense, do we have $D(\overline{A}) = \overline{D(A)} = X$? And why do I see people define $D(\overline{A})$ to be $\{x\in X | \exists x_n\in D(A) \text{ such that } x_n \rightarrow x \text{ and } Ax_n \rightarrow y \text{ for some }y\}.$

**Edit:** I kind see why, because if $Ax_n$ does not converge, then the limit of $(x_n, Ax_n)$ is not necessarily in the closure of $G_A$. And I am thinking about the reason why this does not follow from the general result in topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph is a subspace of $X\times Y$, and it's never going to equal $X\times Y$ unless $X=\{0\}$, $Y=\{0\}$, which keeps you from applying whatever result you were thinking about for $A\times B$.

Here's a simple way to look at the graph of a linear operator:

> **Theorem [Linear Operator Graph]** Let $X$ and $Y$ be vector spaces over the same field. Let $\mathcal{M}\subseteq X\times Y$. Then $\mathcal{M}$ is the graph of a linear operator $A: \mathcal{D}(A)\subseteq X\rightarrow Y$ on a linear domain $\mathcal{D}(A)$ iff $\mathcal{M}$ is a subspace of $X\times Y$ that contains no element $(0,y)\in X\times Y$ other than $(0,0)$.

Suppose you start with a linear operator $A : \mathcal{D}(A)\subseteq X\rightarrow Y$ on the linear domain $\mathcal{D}(A)$. The graph $\mathcal{G}(A)\subseteq X\times Y$ is a subspace with the property stated in the theorem. The closure $\mathcal{M}^c$ of $\mathcal{M}=\mathcal{G}(A)$ is the graph of a linear operator iff the only element $(0,y)\in\mathcal{M}^c$ is $(0,0)$. So $A$ is closable iff $(x_n,Ax_n)\in\mathcal{G}(A)\rightarrow (0,y)$ implies $y=0$. If $A$ is closable to $A^c$, then $\mathcal{D}(A^c)$ is the set of all $x$ in the first coordinate of the elements of $\mathcal{G}(A)^c$, which is the definition you cited.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think I made the mistake thinking that the graph $G_A$ can not be written in the form $D \times B$ where $D =D(A)$ in general.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by TrialandError already explained the given characterization of the domain of the closure. Just some remarks on your first question when $D(\bar A)$ and $X$ coincide:

The operator $\bar A$ is closed by definition. If $D(\bar A)=X$, then $\bar A$ is bounded by the closed graph theorem, and it follows that $A$ is bounded as well. Conversely, if $A$ is bounded, then its closure is defined on $X$:

If $x\in X$, there is a sequence $x_n$ in $D(A)$ such that $x_n\to x$ since $D(A)$ is dense. Boundedness of $A$ implies that $(Ax_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence und thus converges to some $y\in X$. Hence, $x\in D(\bar A)$.

To summarize: $X=D(\bar A)$ if and only if $A$ is bounded.

There are many natural examples of closable operators that are not bounded. As a prominent example, just take $\Delta$ on $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ as an operator on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$.